# Removing Json elements from the Json array if property is empty or missing using jolt transform

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I'm trying to remove JSON elements if the property in the object is missing or null

```
{
  "enterprise": "",
  "Inactive_enterprise_id": null,
  "emp_ID": "123456",
  "Inactive_emp_id": "000821972",
  "Username": "",
  "A_ID": "fsgf1234jhgfs3",
}
```

here is what I am getting:

```
"identifiers" : [ {
      "type" : "enterprise"
    }, {
      "type" : "Inactive_enterprise_id"
    }, {
      "type" : "network"
    }, {
      "identifier" : "123456",
      "type" : "emp_ID"
    }, {
      "identifier" : "000821972",
      "type" : "Inactive_emp_id"
    }, {
      "identifier" : "fsgf1234jhgfs3",
      "type" : "A_ID"
    } ]
```

expected output:

```
"identifiers" : 

    [ 
            {
              "identifier" : "123456",
              "type" : "emp_ID"
            }, {
              "identifier" : "000821972",
              "type" : "Inactive_emp_id"
            }, {
              "identifier" : "fsgf1234jhgfs3",
              "type" : "A_ID"
            } ]
```

I have tried the different JsonSpecs provided on different websites, could able to match expected output. Also tried using two-shift operations but no luck, Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be shifted directly, below link has the workaround,

https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/issues/130

```
[
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "*": ""
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "": "TRASH",
        "*": {
          "@1": "&2"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "TRASH": ""
    }
  }, {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@": "identifiers.[#2].identifier",
        "$": "identifiers.[#2].type"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: appreciate your response but couldn't able to get what I am looking for, I have posted full input JSON here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63196642/removing-json-elements-from-the-json-array-if-property-is-empty-using-jolt-trans